# Unable to stop an A/B testing experiment in the Firebase Console in the Production environment

Tags: firebase, ab-testing

I'm doing an A/B testing on Firebase using remote config. I've already identified the variant I want to roll out in A/B testing. I can successfully roll out the variant in the Beta environment and stop the experiment there using the "stop experiment" option.
My problem is that I can't find a way to stop the experiment in production environment, and I only see the "end experiment" option. I would like to "stop" the experiment immediately and have all users see the variant I've rolled out.

Below are my questions:

1. After rolling out the variant, will all users immediately see the released version?
2. How can I stop the experiment in my Production environment.